# How to list all checked keywords from sentence?

Tags: c#, match, keyword, sentence

This is what I did.

```
List<string> keywords1 = new List<string> { "word1", "word2", "word3" };

string sentence = Console.ReadLine();

int sentenceLength = sentence.Length;

string pattern = String.Join("|", keywords1.Select(k => Regex.Escape(k)));
Match matching = Regex.Match(sentence, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (matching.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(matching);  
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Keyword not found!");
}
```

but if the sentence have every keyword match, I want to list them all.
With the code above, the console just writes the first matching word.

Do I have to use foreach? But how?

For example:
keyword = {"want", "buy", "will", "sell"};
sentence = "I want to buy some food."

Then the result:
want, buy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this would be the easiest:

```
var keyword = new [] {"want", "buy", "will", "sell"};
var sentence = "I want to buy some food." ;

var matches = keyword.Where(k => sentence.Contains(k));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", matches));
```

This results in:

```
want, buy
```

---

Or a more robust version would be:

```
var matches = Regex.Split(sentence, "\\b").Intersect(keyword);
```

This still produces the same output, but avoids matching on the word `"swill"` or `"seller"` if they occurred in the `sentence`.

Comment: what did it show when there's no matching word? i can't count the word with int count = matches.Split().Length; when there's no matching word it always count 1

Comment: @REY - It would show an empty string if there are no matches. I don't know how `int count = matches.Split().Length;` applies to my code. It wouldn't compile with either of my `matches` definitions.

Comment: i just use another regex to find only alfanumeric and it work just fine.
it seems that your code input something that split().length detect so it always count 1 when empty

Comment: @REY - I wish I understood what you just wrote. Do you think you could post your code? That might make it clearer for me.

Comment: sorry. this is the code that I use now. int count = Regex.Matches(matches, @"[A-Za-z0-9]+").Count;......... now i need to make API for this project and i don't know how.. by any chance do you have any link to learn api, parameter url and field like that?

Comment: @REY - I still don't see how `int count = Regex.Matches(matches, @"[A-Za-z0-9]+").Count;` relates to my code. As for learning APIs -that's awfully broad. You're best off doing google searches and seeing what you can find.

Comment: no, i added feature that show how many words that matches. So it's not related to your code above. I just confused when i use .length on empty matches it count as 1 word. so i tried to use regex and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From the question i assume that you are looking for a scenario that, you want to search for the input text(`sentence`) for all items in the list(`keywords1`), if so following snippet will help you to complete the task

```
List<string> keywords1 = new List<string>() { "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4" };
string sentence = Console.ReadLine(); //Let this be "I have word1, searching for word3"
Console.WriteLine("Matching words:");
bool isFound = false;
foreach (string word in keywords1.Where(x => sentence.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
    isFound = true;
}      
if(!isFound)
    Console.WriteLine("No Result");
```

Sample output:

```
input  : "I have word1, searching for word3"
output : Matching words:
word1
word3
```